# Issue with Populating Loan Installment Dates in JavaScript Firebase Application

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a loan management application using JavaScript and Firebase. I'm facing an issue where the loan installment dates (**`datasParcelas`**) are not being populated as expected. Instead, the **`statusParcelas`** array is filled with **`false`** values, and I'm unable to retrieve or display the correct installment dates.

[image]

When I add or edit a loan, the installment dates should be calculated and stored in Firebase. However, the dates are not being saved or retrieved correctly. As a result, the **`statusParcelas`** array, which should contain these dates, only shows **`false`** values.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KylgC.png)

```
function mostrarEmprestimos() {
  if (auth.currentUser) {
    const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
    const emprestimosRef = ref(db, `emprestimos/${userId}`);
    onValue(emprestimosRef, (snapshot) => {
      const emprestimos = snapshot.val();
      console.log("Emprestimos:", emprestimos);
      let html = "";

      const hoje = new Date();
      hoje.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // Configura para meia-noite de hoje

      if (emprestimos) {
        Object.keys(emprestimos).forEach((key) => {
          const emprestimo = emprestimos[key];
          console.log("Emprestimo:", emprestimos[key]);
          let dataEmprestimoFormatada = new Date(
            emprestimo.dataEmprestimo + "T00:00:00",
          ).toLocaleDateString("pt-BR");

          let statusPagamentoHtml =
            emprestimo.datasParcelas && emprestimo.datasParcelas.length > 0
              ? emprestimo.datasParcelas
                  .map((dataParcela, indexParcela) => {
                    const dataParcelaDate = new Date(
                      dataParcela.split("/").reverse().join("-") + "T00:00:00",
                    );
                    const isVencida = dataParcelaDate <= hoje;
                    const isChecked =
                      emprestimo.statusParcelas &&
                      emprestimo.statusParcelas[indexParcela];
                    const parcelaClass = isChecked
                      ? "parcela-paga"
                      : isVencida
                      ? "parcela-vencida"
                      : "parcela-pendente"; // Assume pendente if status is missing
                    const checkedAttribute = isChecked ? "checked" : "";

                    return `
                  <label class="${parcelaClass}">
                      Parcela ${indexParcela + 1} - ${dataParcela}
                      <input type="checkbox" ${checkedAttribute} data-key="${key}" data-index="${indexParcela}">
                  </label>
                  <br>`;
                  })
                  .join("")
              : "<span>Sem informações de parcelas</span>";

          html += `<tr>
            <td><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>${dataEmprestimoFormatada}</td>
            <td>${emprestimo.nomeCliente}</td>
            <td>${formatCurrencyBRL(emprestimo.valorEmprestimo)}</td>
            <td>${emprestimo.taxaJuros.toFixed(2)}%</td>
            <td>${formatCurrencyBRL(emprestimo.valorParcela)}</td>
            <td>${formatCurrencyBRL(emprestimo.valorTotal)}</td>
            <td>${statusPagamentoHtml}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-editar" data-emprestimoId="${key}">Editar</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalConfirmacaoApagar" data-index="${key}">Apagar</button>
            </td>
          </tr>`;
        });
      } else {
        html = '<tr><td colspan="9">Nenhum empréstimo encontrado.</td></tr>';
      }

      $("#tabelaEmprestimos tbody").html(html);

      // Add event listeners to checkboxes
      $("#tabelaEmprestimos tbody input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
          const key = $(this).data("key");
          const index = $(this).data("index");
          alterarStatusPagamento(key, index);
        });
      });
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Nenhum usuário autenticado.");
    alert("Você não está autenticado. Redirecionando para a página de login.");
    window.location.href = "./signin.html";
  }
}
```

```
function adicionarEmprestimo() {
  const dataEmprestimo = $("#dataEmprestimo").val();
  const nomeCliente = $("#nomeCliente").val();
  let valorEmprestimo = parseFloat($("#valorEmprestimo").val());
  if (isNaN(valorEmprestimo)) {
    alert("Por favor, insira um valor numérico para o empréstimo.");
    return;
  }
  let taxaJuros = parseFloat($("#taxaJuros").val()) / 100;
  const frequenciaJuros = $("#frequenciaJuros").val();
  const numeroParcelas = parseInt($("#numeroParcelas").val());

  const jurosPorParcela = (valorEmprestimo * taxaJuros) / numeroParcelas;
  const valorParcela = valorEmprestimo / numeroParcelas + jurosPorParcela;
  const datasParcelas = calcularDatasPagamento(
    dataEmprestimo,
    frequenciaJuros,
    numeroParcelas,
  );
  const valorTotal = valorParcela * numeroParcelas;

  const emprestimo = {
    dataEmprestimo,
    nomeCliente,
    valorEmprestimo,
    taxaJuros: taxaJuros * 100,
    frequenciaJuros,
    numeroParcelas,
    valorParcela,
    valorTotal,
    datasParcelas,
    statusParcelas: new Array(numeroParcelas).fill(false),
  };

  const userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const novoEmprestimoRef = push(ref(db, `emprestimos/${userId}`));
  set(novoEmprestimoRef, emprestimo);

  limparFormulario();
  mostrarEmprestimos();

}
```

```
function editarEmprestimo(emprestimoId) {
  const userId = auth.currentUser?.uid;
  if (!userId) {
    console.log("Nenhum usuário autenticado.");
    return;
  }

  const emprestimoRef = ref(db, `emprestimos/${userId}/${emprestimoId}`);
  onValue(
    emprestimoRef,
    (snapshot) => {
      emprestimoAtual = snapshot.val();
      if (emprestimoAtual) {
        // Atualiza os campos do formulário com os dados do empréstimo
        $("#dataEmprestimo").val(emprestimoAtual.dataEmprestimo);
        $("#nomeCliente").val(emprestimoAtual.nomeCliente);
        $("#valorEmprestimo").val(emprestimoAtual.valorEmprestimo);
        $("#taxaJuros").val(emprestimoAtual.taxaJuros / 100); // Converte a taxa de porcentagem para decimal
        $("#frequenciaJuros").val(emprestimoAtual.frequenciaJuros);
        $("#numeroParcelas").val(emprestimoAtual.numeroParcelas);

        // Verifica se as datas das parcelas estão disponíveis
        if (
          emprestimoAtual.datasParcelas &&
          emprestimoAtual.datasParcelas.length > 0
        ) {
          emprestimoAtual.datasParcelas.forEach((data, index) => {
            // Aqui, você precisa carregar as datas no formulário
            // Certifique-se de que os campos para as datas das parcelas existem
            $("#dataParcela" + (index + 1)).val(data);
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Datas das parcelas não disponíveis");
        }

        // Verifica e atualiza o status de cada parcela
        if (
          emprestimoAtual.statusParcelas &&
          emprestimoAtual.statusParcelas.length > 0
        ) {
          emprestimoAtual.statusParcelas.forEach((status, index) => {
            // Atualiza a interface do usuário para refletir o status de cada parcela
            // Por exemplo, marcar um checkbox como 'checked' se a parcela está paga
            $("#statusParcela" + (index + 1)).prop("checked", status);
          });
        } else {
          console.log("Status das parcelas não disponíveis");
        }

        indiceEmEdicao = emprestimoId;
        $("#botaoAdicionarEmprestimo").text("Salvar Edição");
        console.log("Empréstimo carregado para edição:", emprestimoAtual);
      } else {
        console.log("Empréstimo não encontrado.");
      }
    },
    { onlyOnce: true },
  );
}

$(document).on("click", ".btn-editar", function () {
  const emprestimoId = $(this).attr("data-emprestimoId");
  editarEmprestimo(emprestimoId);
});
```

Comment: The `statusParcelas: new Array(numeroParcelas).fill(false)` in your code seems to match with the values in your database. Which line in your code is supposed to change that `false` to a different value?